# Predicting opening and closing of an organisation

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, supervised-learning

Given Training data of an organisation meter reading recorded at an interval of 15 minutes each day .Like for some N days we will be provided with data.

And Now with help of this data we need to tell that on a particular day an organisation is closed or open . I need to know if any link can help in this matter if someone has worked into this field.

By closed I mean that on that day consumption of electricity will obviously be almost constant,Though this is just a single feature to take into account.

So how to predict this in best way ?

Comment: Take a look at support vector machines

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the use of threshold not suit well for different kind of organisation, but for sure there are a minimum consumption.
Maybe you would like to use the information of past 15 minutes to increase your reliability.
Adding one more input to your classifier.